# Python convert multiple columns to datetime using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, function, datetime, for-loop

I'm stuck on this and looking for community help. I have a few columns within a dataframe that are labeled as objects but would like to convert to datetime. All columns have year,month,day criteria.

```
time = np.array(['time1','time2','time3'])
```

```
def cols_to_datetime(df):

   cols_to_datetime = time

   for col in cols_to_datetime:
       df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])

   return df
```

Although all have year, month, day i'm receiving this error

```
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

df -

```
time1                      time2                      time3 
2020-06-06 20:01:10.327    2020-06-06 22:08:14.832    2020-06-06
```

There may be nulls in the df that would need to be skipped.

I did test without them and didn't have luck. So I'm not quite sure why this approach doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Please post an example of your dataframe

Comment: beware using things like `time` for variable names... plus it will be data specific

Comment: i've added a simplified df sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html).

- [numpy dtype reference](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)
- [datetime64 is used here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

def convert_times(df, cols=None):
    if not cols:
        # if no columns are specified, use all
        cols = df.columns
    df[cols] = df[cols].astype('datetime64')
    return df

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'created_at': ['2020-06-06 20:01:10.327'],
    'updated_at': ['2020-06-06 22:08:14.832']
})
print(df.dtypes)
# created_at    object
# updated_at    object
# dtype: object

df2 = convert_times(df)
print(df2.dtypes)
# created_at    datetime64[ns]
# updated_at    datetime64[ns]
# dtype: object
```

Comment: if one of the dfs does not have all of the columns, how can i account for that easily?

Comment: Do you mean the case in which your dataframe has a lot of columns, but you only want to make a subset of those into datetime? Use `convert_times(df, ['col1', 'col2'])`. All other columns of the dataframe won't be touched.

Comment: if a df has time1 only but another df has time1,time2,time3. i'm running this on a few dfs, so i get a not in index error if not all times columns are in the df

Comment: Then you would have to use `convert_times(df1, ['time1', 'time2']); convert_times(df2, ['anothertime1', 'anothertime2'])`